# How to timeout execution of function

Tags: c#, timeout, locking

I would like the limit the time how long the function should execute. If it takes too long it should stop execution (if needed throw exception). 
The reason why i want it because sometimes the code inside lock takes forever, and all threads that want to access the lock statement can't access it.

Example:

```
lock(objLock){
   DoWork();
}
```

So i would like to limit time of execution of function DoWork() so to prevent that other threads wait forever to enter the lock. It doesn't help me to limit how long other threads should wait to enter.

Comment: Maybe you need to pay attention to the code which "takes forever" because it doesn't seem be normal behavior of well-designed code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use another thread to do the work and the current thread to be the monitor:

```
lock(objLock){
    Thread workerThread = new Thread(DoWork);
    workerThread.Start();

    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    bool finished = workerThread.Join(timeout);
    if (!finished) workerThread.Abort();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually Adding like below:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
while(Datetime.Now - dt > Atimespan)
{Do some work}
```

Or you can check for time in the loop

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
lock(objLock){
   DoWork();
   if(DateTime.Now - dt > SomeTimeSpan) break;
}
```